# Parse Server ACL setting in mongoLab

Tags: swift, acl, parse-server

when I use the code below in my xcode xwift project, in the mongolab part the objects are written as below, and the ACL settings in the parse dashboard are not changed.

```
let acl = PFACL()
acl.publicReadAccess = true
acl.publicWriteAccess = false
userSettingObj["ACL"] = acl

 "_rperm": [
    "*"
  ],
```

However when I make the changes from the dashboard of parse, the mongolab acl record is like:

```
"_acl": {
      "*": {
        "r": true
    },
},

 "_rperm": [
  "*"
  ],
```

The "_acl" part in the mongolab objects are missing when I update the ACL with the code above as it is stated in parse documents. What may be the reason?

Comment: Can you provide more of your code? Especially the part where you save `userSettingObj`.

Comment: Hello Simon, I learned that it is normal beause of the migration process from parse to parseServer. Only the "_acl" part in the database is enough for the permissions. Thank you.

Comment: Sweet! You might want to consider answering your own question to let others with the same problem know.